# Filter keys of object such that only keys pointing to array are returned (instead of all keys by 'keyof')

Tags: typescript

For `student.ts`

```
type Student = {
    name: string,
    marks: string[],
    subjects: string[]
}
```

How to get `ArrayKey<Student>` such that it return only keys which points to any array, here it should point to `'marks'|'subjects'`

**My try**

```
type ArrayKey<T, Key extends keyof T = keyof T> = T[Key] extends any[] ? Key : never;

let c: ArrayKey<Student> = 'marks';
```

but it throws error `[ts] Type '"marks"' is not assignable to type 'never'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but your code requires the developer to specify `Key`, which is what you're trying to output. You can instead use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to iterate over the keys of `T` and then use your conditional type to identify the ones with array-valued properties.  Like this:

```
type ArrayKey<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends any[] ? Key : never }[keyof T];

type Student = {
  name: string,
  marks: string[],
  subjects: string[]
}

let c: ArrayKey<Student> = 'marks'; // okay
```

---

Another way to do it which is closer to your original definition would be to use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) to distribute the conditional over the contituents of `K`:

```
type ArrayKey<T, Key extends keyof T = keyof T> = 
   Key extends any ? T[Key] extends any[] ? Key : never : never
```

That will also work, but `K` has to be a bare type parameter and `Key extends any` might be confusing (distributive conditional types are a bit surprising) and it's abusing the default value of `K` as a hack, so I wouldn't recommend it.  Less hacky but still using distributive conditional types:

```
type ArrayKeyInner<T, Key extends keyof T> =
   Key extends any ? T[Key] extends any[] ? Key : never : never
type ArrayKey<T> = ArrayKeyInner<T, keyof T>
```

That doesn't abuse a default parameter, which is nice.  Still, the distributive conditional type surprise factor still holds so overall I'd still recommend the mapped type solution.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!